# Reverse linked list - how to remove "None" which is coming at the end (of output)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, reverse

I am solving this problem on leetcode - [Reverse linked list](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/)

My code is running fine I believe but I am receiving "None" in the output. How can I remove this?

This is how output is coming for the input `[1,2,3,4,5]`:

> > > Output: `[5,4,3,2,1,None]`

Here is the code I tried:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:

        if head is None: return None

        if head.next is None: return head

        cur = head
        prev = ListNode(None)
        temp = head.next

        while temp:
            cur.next = prev
            prev = cur
            cur = temp
            temp = temp.next

        if temp is None:
            cur.next = prev

        head = cur
        return head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `prev = ListNode(None)` you create a new Node with `value = None` and next Node `None`.
So, in your example `Node 1` does not have None as `self.next`, but a Node with None as self.val.

```
prev = None
```

should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As a complementary answer, you are using too many useless if statements that you could avoid. Similarly to your answer, your could reduce it simply to the following:

```
def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
prev = None

while head:
    temp  = head.next
    head.next = prev
    prev = head
    head = temp

return prev
```